# DirectShow virtual camera sample don't compile with linker errors

Tags: driver, directshow

i'm trying to compile virtual camera [sample](https://github.com/rdp/open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter) in VS2015, but have a lot of linker errors:

```
strmbasd.lib(wxlist.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int)" (??2@YAPAXI@Z)
Filters.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int)" (??2@YAPAXI@Z)
strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int)" (??2@YAPAXI@Z)
strmbasd.lib(dllentry.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int)" (??2@YAPAXI@Z)
strmbasd.lib(amfilter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int)" (??2@YAPAXI@Z)
strmbasd.lib(amfilter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3@YAXPAXI@Z)
strmbasd.lib(source.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3@YAXPAXI@Z)
strmbasd.lib(wxlist.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3@YAXPAXI@Z)
Filters.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3@YAXPAXI@Z)
strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3@YAXPAXI@Z)
strmbasd.lib(dllentry.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3@YAXPAXI@Z)
strmbasd.lib(wxutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3@YAXPAXI@Z)
Filters.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl operator new[](unsigned int)" (??_U@YAPAXI@Z) referenced in function "private: __thiscall CVCam::CVCam(struct IUnknown *,long *)" (??0CVCam@@AAE@PAUIUnknown@@PAJ@Z)
strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl operator new[](unsigned int)" (??_U@YAPAXI@Z)
strmbasd.lib(amfilter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl operator new[](unsigned int)" (??_U@YAPAXI@Z)
strmbasd.lib(source.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl operator new[](unsigned int)" (??_U@YAPAXI@Z)
strmbasd.lib(combase.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _memcmp
strmbasd.lib(mtype.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _memcmp
strmbasd.lib(amfilter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _memcmp
Filters.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _memcmp
strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _memcmp
strmbasd.lib(dllentry.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _memcmp
strmbasd.lib(amvideo.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _memcmp
Filters.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _memset referenced in function "public: virtual long __thiscall CVCamStream::GetMediaType(int,class CMediaType *)" (?GetMediaType@CVCamStream@@UAEJHPAVCMediaType@@@Z)
strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _memset
strmbasd.lib(mtype.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _memset
strmbasd.lib(amfilter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _memset
Filters.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__rand referenced in function "public: virtual long __thiscall CVCamStream::FillBuffer(struct IMediaSample *)" (?FillBuffer@CVCamStream@@UAEJPAUIMediaSample@@@Z)
Filters.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const type_info::`vftable'" (??_7type_info@@6B@)
strmbasd.lib(dllentry.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const type_info::`vftable'" (??_7type_info@@6B@)
strmbasd.lib(amfilter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const type_info::`vftable'" (??_7type_info@@6B@)
strmbasd.lib(source.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const type_info::`vftable'" (??_7type_info@@6B@)
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __DllMainCRTStartup@12
strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete[](void *)" (??_V@YAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall CDispBasic::~CDispBasic(void)" (??1CDispBasic@@QAE@XZ)
strmbasd.lib(amfilter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete[](void *)" (??_V@YAXPAX@Z)
strmbasd.lib(source.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete[](void *)" (??_V@YAXPAX@Z)
strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___report_rangecheckfailure referenced in function "public: __thiscall CDisp::CDisp(__int64,int)" (??0CDisp@@QAE@_JH@Z)
strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__wcsrchr referenced in function "wchar_t * __cdecl wcsrchr(wchar_t *,wchar_t)" (?wcsrchr@@YAPA_WPA_W_W@Z)
strmbasd.lib(dllentry.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wcsrchr
strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vswprintf referenced in function __vsnwprintf_l
strmbasd.lib(dllsetup.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vswprintf
strmbasd.lib(dllentry.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vswprintf
strmbasd.lib(wxutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vswprintf
strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsprintf referenced in function __vsnprintf_l
strmbasd.lib(wxlist.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @_RTC_CheckStackVars@8
strmbasd.lib(amvideo.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @_RTC_CheckStackVars@8
strmbasd.lib(combase.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @_RTC_CheckStackVars@8
strmbasd.lib(amfilter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @_RTC_CheckStackVars@8
strmbasd.lib(source.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @_RTC_CheckStackVars@8
strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @_RTC_CheckStackVars@8
strmbasd.lib(dllsetup.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @_RTC_CheckStackVars@8
strmbasd.lib(dllentry.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @_RTC_CheckStackVars@8
strmbasd.lib(wxutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @_RTC_CheckStackVars@8
strmbasd.lib(amvideo.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
strmbasd.lib(mtype.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
strmbasd.lib(amfilter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
strmbasd.lib(source.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
strmbasd.lib(dllsetup.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
strmbasd.lib(dllentry.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
strmbasd.lib(wxutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
strmbasd.lib(source.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_CheckEsp
strmbasd.lib(wxlist.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_CheckEsp
strmbasd.lib(amvideo.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_CheckEsp
strmbasd.lib(combase.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_CheckEsp
strmbasd.lib(mtype.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_CheckEsp
strmbasd.lib(amfilter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_CheckEsp
strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_CheckEsp
strmbasd.lib(dllsetup.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_CheckEsp
strmbasd.lib(dllentry.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_CheckEsp
strmbasd.lib(wxutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_CheckEsp
strmbasd.lib(source.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase
strmbasd.lib(wxlist.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase
strmbasd.lib(amvideo.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase
strmbasd.lib(combase.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase
strmbasd.lib(mtype.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase
strmbasd.lib(amfilter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase
strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase
strmbasd.lib(dllsetup.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase
strmbasd.lib(dllentry.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase
strmbasd.lib(wxutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase
strmbasd.lib(source.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
strmbasd.lib(wxlist.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
strmbasd.lib(amvideo.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
strmbasd.lib(combase.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
strmbasd.lib(mtype.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
strmbasd.lib(amfilter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
strmbasd.lib(dllsetup.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
strmbasd.lib(dllentry.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
strmbasd.lib(wxutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __alldiv referenced in function "public: __thiscall CDisp::CDisp(class CRefTime)" (??0CDisp@@QAE@VCRefTime@@@Z)
strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __allrem referenced in function "public: __thiscall CDisp::CDisp(class CRefTime)" (??0CDisp@@QAE@VCRefTime@@@Z)
strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __chkstk referenced in function "void __cdecl DbgBreakPoint(wchar_t const *,int,wchar_t const *,...)" (?DbgBreakPoint@@YAXPB_WH0ZZ)
strmbasd.lib(amvideo.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
strmbasd.lib(mtype.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
strmbasd.lib(amfilter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
strmbasd.lib(source.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
strmbasd.lib(dllsetup.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
strmbasd.lib(dllentry.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
strmbasd.lib(wxutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __fltused
strmbasd.lib(amfilter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __fltused
strmbasd.lib(dllentry.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___security_init_cookie referenced in function _DllEntryPoint@12
strmbasd.lib(wxutil.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _memcpy referenced in function _AMGetWideString@8
strmbasd.lib(mtype.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _memcpy
strmbasd.lib(amfilter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _memcpy
strmbasd.lib(source.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _memcpy
strmbasd.lib(wxutil.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __RTC_UninitUse referenced in function "public: int __thiscall CAMMsgEvent::WaitMsg(unsigned long)" (?WaitMsg@CAMMsgEvent@@QAEHK@Z)
strmbasd.lib(amfilter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __purecall
strmbasd.lib(source.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __purecall
strmbasd.lib(amfilter.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __allmul referenced in function "protected: virtual long __thiscall CMemAllocator::Alloc(void)" (?Alloc@CMemAllocator@@MAEJXZ)
strmbasd.lib(source.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___wtoi referenced in function "public: virtual long __stdcall CSource::FindPin(wchar_t const *,struct IPin * *)" (?FindPin@CSource@@UAGJPB_WPAPAUIPin@@@Z)
```

Linker command line:

```
   /OUT:"C:\Users\Администратор.000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\virtual-camera-demo\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\Debug\vcam_vs_2010.ax" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\Администратор.000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\virtual-camera-demo\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\Debug\vcam_vs_2010.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses\Debug\strmbasd.lib" "strmiids.lib" "winmm.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEF:"Filters.def" /IMPLIB:"C:\Users\Администратор.000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\virtual-camera-demo\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\Debug\vcam_vs_2010.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\Users\Администратор.000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\virtual-camera-demo\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\Debug\vcam_vs_2010.pgd" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Debug\vcam_vs_2010.ax.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /NODEFAULTLIB /TLBID:1
```

I have compiled strmbasd.lib, included all necessary libraries, checked unicode character set and compiler settings from baseclasses project, tried downloaded compiled strmbasd.lib, but i can't understand what is wrong. How to make this sample compile successfully?

Comment: Most likely there are still important changes between BaseClasses and your project, so that linking the two together still yield unresolved external symbols

Comment: I simply took sample project and baseclasses libs and tried to compile the sample, i think the biggest difference that could be is the version of VS projects. I found some advices about recompiling the baseclasses strmbasd.lib with the same compiler as i use to compile sample and i did it but nothing changed.

Comment: It still looks like compiler/linker options mismatch. However as a workaround you can replace strmbas?.lib linkage with direct inclusion of its files into DLL project (if you give up trying to sort out static library linking).

Comment: I tryed to add all .cpp and .h files from baseclasses to the project but still has the same errors.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get directshow vcam sample to work on Windows 10 w\ VS 2013 or VS 2015 and I spent countless hours on it.

I was able to get this working in a Win7 x86 Virtual Machine in about 30 mins. I'll probably go through and revalidate these at some point

step 1: Create Windows 7 Virtual Machine x86

step 2: get sdk

```
* [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442][1]
```

step 3: get 2010 samples

```
* https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812
* installs files program files\microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)
* this step is probably not needed.
```

step 4: dl visual studio 2013

```
* [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=517284][1]
```

step 5: install git

```
* install git
* mkdir projects
* git clone https://github.com/johnmaccormick/MultiCam
* cd MultiCam
```

Step 6:

```
* import these \baseclasses into a project c:\projects\baseclasses
* 
    * C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses
    * I think these build first time, didn't change anything that I can remember
```

Step 7:

```
* open multicam project
* vcam project properties-->library directories
* add C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\lib
* add c:\projects\baseclasses\debug
* compile win32
```

Comment: This... I also tried for hours to get it to build on Windows 10, in the end, after getting Windows 7 installed this only took 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon the same while trying to make an audio renderer filter with Visual Studio 2015. I managed to get it linking though (with the `/NODEFAULTLIBS` flag) by adding the needed libraries and some weird stuff from crt runtime sources (`initializers.cpp` to be exact). You can check out https://github.com/rubu/VirtualAudioRenderer.

Comment: github link is broken.

Comment: @PypeBros yeah it seems I've deleted the repo (since it seemed useless, because it was just some libs and a file). I can try to set it up again, if the stuff I mentioned doing in the answer is not explicit enough.

Comment: knowing what weird stuff were in initializers.cpp would help, indeed.

Comment: @PypeBros ok, let me focus my memory (since I do not have a Windows machine by hand now) - the file came from MSVC C/C++ runtime sources (so basically just run a search in the folders where Visual Studio and Windows SDK are installed for the file initializers.cpp) - i either copied the file to my project or copied the code from the file inline in main.cpp.

Comment: @PypeBros Googling around seems that it is in the Visual Studio folder under `VC/crt/src/vcruntime/initializers.cpp`